# Indentation on a long (ish) linq chain

Tags: c#, linq, comparative-review

I have some code that loops through directories named for years (e.g. `/2011/`, `/2012/` etc) which each contain files whose names end with dates in the "yyyyMMdd" format, and builds a list of all the dates in all the directories. But what is the best way to indent this, nothing I've tried is readable:

```
files = files.Union(
    Directory.GetFiles(year)
             .Select(d => DateTime.ParseExact(
      Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(d)
          .Substring(
         Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(d)
             .Length - 8),
     "yyyyMMdd",
     null))).ToList();
```

or

```
files = files.Union(Directory.GetFiles(year)
                             .Select(d => DateTime.ParseExact(
                                                              Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(d).Substring(
                                                                                                    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(d).Length - 8),
                                                              "yyyyMMdd",
                                                              null)
                                     )
                    ).ToList();
```

or

```
files = files.Union(Directory.GetFiles(year)
                             .Select(d => DateTime.ParseExact(
                                                              Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(d).Substring(
                                                                                                            Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(d).Length - 8),
                                                              "yyyyMMdd",
                                                              null))).ToList();
```

or

```
files = files.Union(Directory.GetFiles(year).Select(d => DateTime.ParseExact(
                    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(d).Substring(
                    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(d).Length - 8),
                    "yyyyMMdd", null))).ToList();
```

Comment: What content will `year` have as example ?

Comment: @Heslacher string to a directory e.g. `@"C:\Datafiles\2011"`. This is in a `foreach` loop the goes through all subdirectories of the example directory `C:\Datafiles\ ` whose names are acceptable as years

Comment: **"Comparative Review" tag: I have a problem. Here are my X solutions. Which one would be best? Is there an alternative option to these solutions?** Why do you feel this tag shouldn't be on the question? If you feel more comfortable in chat we can discuss it there http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor

Comment: @Pimgd because I think I presented 4 bad solutions, I don't want to know which is best out of them but rather (as the answers so far have shown) I am looking for an alternative to all 4 (which are all rubbish imo). So my problem is that it might be misleading to tag this as "Comparative Review" because of the statement in your description "Which one would be best?", I know none are best, I just put them there to show that I've tried a few configurations and that none are really suitable

Comment: Usually you post a comparative review because you can't decide for yourself; Either both options are good, and you don't know which is better, or both options are bad, and you need help picking the lesser evil. A great answer on a question like that eliminates the choice by presenting a third option which is even better. A good answer just picks one of the provided solutions and explains why that one is better than the others. You can't really avoid that; even without the tag, "I think the last option is best because x y and z" would be a perfectly valid answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Naming**

As the purpose of this `linq` query is to build a `List<DateTime>` where you only need the `Date` part, a better name would be **dates** instead of **files**.

As `year` doesn't contain a year, but a foldername let us change the name to yearlyFolderName.

**Refactoring**

Let us introduce a method which will expect a folderName and a dateFormat each as `String` and returns a `IEnumerable<DateTime>`.

```
private IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDatesFromFileNames(String containingFolder, String datePattern)
{
    return Directory.GetFiles(containingFolder)
        .Select(s => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s))
        .Select(s => s.Substring(s.Length - 8))
        .Select(s => DateTime.ParseExact(s, datePattern, null));
}
```

As we use a additional `Select()` to firstly get the filenames without extension, then using another `Select()` to get only the date part and last another `Select()` we can neat indent this `linq` query.

we will add an overload to reflect your current dateformat also

```
private IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDatesFromFileNames(String containingFolder)
{
    return GetDatesFromFileNames(containingFolder, "yyyyMMdd");
}
```

Now you can call it

```
dates = dates.Union(GetDatesFromFileNames(yearlyFolderName)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks this looks a lot better. Why do you use `String` instead of `string`?

Comment: @Dan Because I am used to it ;-) Today my keyboard is swallowing letters a lot. Updated answer.

Answer (score 10):

I would consider refactoring the `.Select` call to do this:

```
files = files.Union(Directory.GetFiles(year).Select(d => GetTimeForFile(d))).ToList();
```

Where `GetTimeForFile` is a method with the following content:

```
DateTime GetTimeForFile(String fileName)
{
    var noExtName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
    return DateTime.ParseExact(noExtName.Substring(noExtName.Length - 8),
     "yyyyMMdd", null);
}
```

Either way, no matter how you indent it now, the method extraction of `GetTimeForFile` makes it significantly more readable.

Comment: Gave this a shot using a `Func<>` instead of a function and ran into the following issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26155281/why-does-lambda-expression-assume-char-instead-of-string but otherwise I do like this suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I always try to vertically align according to the nesting level. If it still looks messy, I try to refactor the statement which I would do in this case using a regular expression :)

```
//match strings ending with 8 numerals followed by the literal string .ext
var regex = new Regex(@"(\d{8})\.ext$");

var files = Directory
    .GetFiles(path)
    .Select(f => regex.Match(f).Groups[0].Value)
    .Select(d => DateTime.ParseExact(d, "yyyyMMdd", null))
    .ToList();
```

Note: You could easily modify the above to do a recursive GetFiles from your root data directory, avoiding the multiple calls to `files.Union`.

Observe the multiple selects which I chose for readability. You could simplify your statement using the same trick:

```
files = files.Union(
   Directory
      .GetFiles(year)
      .Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension)
      .Select(d => DateTime.ParseExact(d.Substring(d.Length-8),"yyyyMMdd", null)));
```

Also, you could consider breaking out the parsing to a function. This increases readability more and enables you to easily test the function:

```
static DateTime ParseDate(string fileNameWithoutExtension)
{
   var idx = d.Length - 8;
   var dateString = fileNameWithoutExtension.Substring(idx);
   return DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMdd", null);
}
```

and pass the function to the linq statement:

```
files = files.Union(
   Directory
   .GetFiles(year)
   .Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension)
   .Select(ParseDate));
```